# Unable to get Javascript app to display 4 images at the same time as button for a quiz

Tags: javascript, events, datatables

I am trying to get 4 images to show up into 4 buttons. I am only getting one at a time. I need it to all be at the same time and for all of it to change once on button is clicked. Possible problem in the onEvent or the first if statement.  This is for an quiz app.  The grading function will come later once I am able to get the dog images to appear together and the click to work for the quiz.

```
var allDogs = getColumn("Dogs", "Name");
var allDogsPicturesList = getColumn("Dogs", "Image");
var questionNumber;
var dogImage;
var dogName;
var correctDog;
var userChoice;
var score;
setScreen("startScreen");
onEvent("readyButton", "click", function( ) {
  setScreen("quizScreen");
  gameQuestionsAndEnd();
});
onEvent("dog1", "click", function( ) {
  userChoice = getImageURL("dog1");
  gameQuestionsAndEnd();
});
onEvent("dog2", "click", function( ) {
  userChoice = getImageURL("dog2");
  gameQuestionsAndEnd();
});
onEvent("dog3", "click", function( ) {
  userChoice = getImageURL("dog3");
  gameQuestionsAndEnd();
});
onEvent("dog4", "click", function( ) {
  userChoice = getImageURL("dog4");
  gameQuestionsAndEnd();
});
function gameQuestionsAndEnd(answerRight, answerWrong) {
    dogName =(randomNumber(0, allDogs.length-1));
    dogImage = (randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length-1));
    correctDog = allDogsPicturesList[dogName];
    answerRight = dogName;
    var box = randomNumber(1,4);
    setText("dogBeingGuessed", "Which dog is a " + "\n" + allDogs[dogName]);
    for (var w = 0; w <= 10; w++) {
    setProperty("dog"+box, "image", allDogsPicturesList[dogName]);
    if ("dog1"==allDogs[dogName]) {
        setProperty("dog2", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
        setProperty("dog3", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
        setProperty("dog4", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
      questionNumber = questionNumber+1;
    } else if ("dog2"==dogName) {
        setProperty("dog1", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
        setProperty("dog3", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
        setProperty("dog4", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
      questionNumber = questionNumber+1;
    } else if ("dog3"==dogName) {
        setProperty("dog2", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
        setProperty("dog1", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
        setProperty("dog4", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
      questionNumber = questionNumber+1;
    } else if ("dog4"==dogName) {
        setProperty("dog2", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
        setProperty("dog3", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
        setProperty("dog1", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
      questionNumber = questionNumber+1;
    }
    if (answerRight==userChoice) {
    score = score+1;
  }
    if (answerWrong) {
    score = score-1;
      }
    questionNumber = questionNumber+1;
  }
    if (questionNumber==10) {
      setScreen("screen1");
    }
}
```

Tried working different event options.